# message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, html

im new with php. i cannot see what the error in this code.
please help me. i getting this error
'message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null'

```js
   //insert new product
$app->post('/products/inserts', function ($request, $response,$args){

  $form_data = $request->getParsedBody();
  //return $this->response->withJson($form_data, 200);
  
  $data = createProduct($this->db, $form_data);
    if ($data<= 0){
      return $this->response->withJson(array('error'=> 'fail'), 500);

    return $this->response->withJson(array('data'=> 'success'), 200);
    }
});
//insert new product
function createProduct($db, $form_data)
{ 
    $sql = 'Insert into products (name, description, price, category_id, created)';
    $sql .= 'values (:name, :description, :price, :category_id, :created)';
    $stmt = $db->prepare ($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $form_data['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $form_data['description']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $form_data['price']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', floatval($form_data['price']));
    $stmt->bindParam(':created', $form_data['created']);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $db->lastinsertID(); //insert last number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$form_data['name'] should be not empty. you can handle this by checking if it is empty or not through
`isset($form_data['name'])? $form_data['name']: '';`